# Using Angular Directive for multiple options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a site footer:

```
    <footer>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="contents">
      <div class="logo-copyright">
        <div class="footer-logo">
           <i class="footer-logo gradient"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">&copy; 2016 A Company, Inc.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-terms"><a href="">Terms of use</a></div>
      <div class="footer-legal"><a href="">Legal Info</a></div>
      <div class="footer-contact"><a href="">Contact Us</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I would like to put this is a directive so it can be used as something like `<my-footer></my-footer>`

I know how to it "as is", but my issue is that parts of this footer might not be needed in some applications.  Although `logo-copyright` is required for everyone, its three siblings might be needed or not.

What I am looking for is a way to use the directive with options that would show the respective `div`s as needed for example:

`<my-footer options="terms legal"></my-footer>`

Would display the html with the 2 divs `footer-terms` and `footer-legal` but not `footer-contact`, whereas

`<my-footer></my-footer>`

would show the footer html with only the required `logo-copyright` div and omit the other 2.

I am very unclear on how to proceed in implementing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will have my directive accept three values:

```
<my-footer terms legal contact></my-footer>
```

And below would be my directive definition, i would use `attrs` over `scope`.

```
.directive('myFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false
        templateUrl: '/partials/footer.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.terms = typeof attrs.terms != 'undefined';
            scope.legal = typeof attrs.legal != 'undefined';
            scope.contact = typeof attrs.contact != 'undefined';
        }
    }
})
```

This would ensure your html part is pretty clean by ensuring only loading the components/template section of needed ones.

```
<my-footer terms legal></my-footer>
```

Would ensure only `terms and legal` section are loaded.

Here is a fiddle for the same: 
https://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/wakajwzt/

Comment: Thanks, but the most confusing part for me is how to ties this to an HTML template, to include the respective divs or not.  Can you please show an example?

Comment: @Steve: in your footer.html use all the templates... and use an ng-if condition for scope.contact, legel and terms... which will be bound and use replace: true in your directive